# ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am running Apache Spark using Java on below configuration :

1) **100 Million** input rows

2) `spark-submit` configuration : `--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=120 --total-executor-cores=120 --executor-memory=60GB --driver-memory=50G --executor-cores=10 --driver-cores=10`

3) 1 Master and 2 Workers : **Each worker has 502 GB of Memory and 88 Virtual CPUs.**

I tried running with default value of `spark.network.timeout` but it gave error :

```
has been quiet for 120000 ms while there are outstanding requests. Assuming connection is dead; please adjust spark.network.timeout if this is wrong.
```

Hence I changed value of **spark.network.timeout to 300000 ms.**

Now There is no error in the code except below log:

```
18/12/24 06:02:39 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 874
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 934
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 850
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 898
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 886
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 946
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 958
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 910
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 862
18/12/24 08:27:10 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
4 bytes, TID = 934
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 850
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 898
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 886
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 946
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 958
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 910
18/12/24 08:22:57 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 262144 bytes, TID = 862
```

**Here Program ends without error but it has not processed all records. It is giving partial results for some of the records.**

I can't share the code because of proprietary issues.

My question is  : ***should i changes anything in my existing configuration? or it has to do anything with my hardware?***

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue and if so how? I see lots of memory leak detected error is the log you posted?